# How to logout the ubuntu while remain vnc session connected?

Tags: command-line, gnome, vnc, logout

Ubuntu server 14.04 Trusty.
Using vnc4server, gnome-shell.

I am trying to logout the user but with no luck.
What I am trying to achieve is to end all the tasks that the user is processing,like closing all the applications, all the scripts that he is running, but keep the vnc session on, so the user can still connect to it after logging out.

I have tried several approaches:

1. Add logout button in the task bar, but it does nothing.
2. Type 'logout' in the terminal, but returned
   bash: logout: no login shell: use 'exit'
3. Type 'exit' in the terminal, this just quits the terminal.
4. Type gnome-session-quit --logout in the terminal, but I got an error:
   WARNING **:Failed to call logout: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files.

Is that because there's no session ?
I'm totally lost here. 
Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: What actual workflow are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm trying to close all working processes under this user, like the application he opens, scripts are currently running, but keep the vncserver session running on this user, so the user can always remote connect to the server.

Comment: Logging out of a GUI session will kill the Xserver, ending the VNC session whether you like it or not. The login screen does not use X, and X does not start until a user logs in.

Comment: @user535733 Thx for your reply. Do you know why the logout button/gnome-session-quit does not work?